# Member function class without stl and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

I wrote the example below which uses no standard library to call a class member function. This works as expected but I want to make it more generic. This is intended for embedded systems with 8bit microcontrollers. I don't want to provoke a discussion whether to use C++ for this kind of architecture.

The code works as follows: Using a void pointer for a class member function or a function is not possible. Though it is possible to use void pointers for single functions but this is not well defined behaviour.

In this case I use a static function for calling the class member. The method caller function is a static template function which accepts the object type and a member function pointer as template arguments.

The bind function stores the object pointer as void pointer and sets callingFunction inside the class to the specific static method. When the call happens with the () operator, the callingFunction pointer gets called with the specific object and all parameters.

All this works as expected and can be compiled with C++11 enabled due to variadic templates. My intention is to make the api more comfortable. Using f.bind(&t) all the time seems to be a bit long but I don't know any better way to do this. Any ideas?

Another point is to store functions, which are not part of a class.

```
#include <iostream>

class testclass {
public:
    virtual char test(void){
        return '.';
    }
};

class testclass2 : public testclass{
public:
    char test(void){
        return '@';
    }
};

template<typename signature>
class Function;

template<typename TReturn, typename ...TParam>
class Function<TReturn(TParam...)> {
public:
    template<typename TObject, TReturn (TObject::*TMethod)(TParam...)>
    void bind(TObject *obj){
        this->obj = obj;
        this->callingFunction = &methodCaller<TObject, TMethod>;
    }

    TReturn operator()(TParam... params){
        return callingFunction(this->obj, params...);
    }
private:
    void *obj;
    TReturn (*callingFunction)(void *obj, TParam...);

    template<typename TObject, TReturn (TObject::*TMethod)(TParam...)>
    static TReturn methodCaller(void *obj, TParam... params) {
        TObject *c = static_cast<TObject*>(obj);
        return (c->*TMethod)(params...);
    }
};

int main(){
    testclass t;

    Function<char(void)> f;
    f.bind<testclass, &testclass::test>(&t);
    std::cout << f();

    testclass2 t1 = testclass2();
    f.bind<testclass, &testclass::test>(&t1);
    std::cout << f();
}
```

Comment: Which interface do you expect ? Do you want something like `std::bind(&testclass::test, &t /*, _1, _2 */);`

Comment: A better interface would be f.bind(&t, &testclass::test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allows your expected interface

```
template<typename signature> class Function;

template<typename TReturn, typename ...TParam>
class Function<TReturn(TParam...)> {
private:
    template <typename Obj>
    struct Helper
    {
        Obj* obj;
        TReturn (Obj::*m)(TParam...);

        Helper(Obj* obj, TReturn (Obj::*m)(TParam...)) : obj(obj), m(m) {}

        template <typename ... Args>
        TReturn call(Args&&... args) { return (obj->*m)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    };

public:
    template<typename TObject>
    void bind(TObject *obj, TReturn (TObject::*m)(TParam...)){
        this->obj = std::make_shared<Helper<TObject>>(obj, m);
        this->callingFunction = &methodCaller<TObject>;
    }

    TReturn operator()(TParam&&... params){
        return callingFunction(this->obj.get(), std::forward<TParam>(params)...);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> obj;
    TReturn (*callingFunction)(void* obj, TParam...);

    template<typename TObject>
    static TReturn methodCaller(void *obj, TParam... params) {
        auto* c = static_cast<Helper<TObject>*>(obj);
        return c->call(std::forward<TParam>(params)...);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9abdda8a58e94b)

I let you replace `std::shared_ptr` in you want to get rid of standard library with your own smart pointer.

Comment: There is no dynamic memory allocation and no way to use std:: at all.

Comment: I used std::cout only for testing the output but the final code will run on 8 bit processor